# Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial, 7.3 Capybara::ElementNotFound

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, railstutorial.org

I'm in [Section 7.3.1](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-a_working_form) of the Hartl's Rails tutorial and am getting the following error:

```
Capybara::ElementNotFound:
   no button with value or id or text 'Create my account' found
```

but as far as I can tell, the button with that value DOES exist.

here's the new.html.erb code:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="span6 offset3">
        <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>



            <%= f.label :name %>
            <%= f.text_field :name %>

            <%= f.label :email %>
            <%= f.text_field :email %>

            <%= f.label :password %>
            <%= f.password_field :password %>

            <%= f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirmation" %>
            <%= f.password_field :password_confirmation %>

            <%= f.submit "Create my acccount", class: "btn btn-large btn-primary" %>
        <% end %>
    </div>
</div>
```

anyone have any ideas here?

also, here's a section of the test:

```
describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
```

it might also be worth nothing that both "with valid information" and "with invalid information" are failing.

Comment: There is an extra 'c' in __account__: `<%= f.submit "Create my acccount"`.

Comment: that's it! thank you! now how do i up vote a comment?

Comment: There is a [minimum reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#reputation) required to upvote comments.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how you are calling it in Capybara but try to add an ID to the submit button and call by ID in capybara.
By the docs you should be calling the [click_button method](http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Actions#click_button-instance_method).

Comment: i added a section of the test file where you can see me calling the click_button method.

Comment: Have a look at the launchy gem, install the gem and use the method save_and_open_page after you visit the signup_path. You can verify what HTML is being rendered after you hit that signup_path to see if your button is indeed being rendered, or even if signup path is taking you to the right place.